# Parsing XML with PowerShell with date comparison

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing, powershell-3.0

Could you please help me to debug my code.

I'm using a Powershell script to parse a large amount of XML files from one folder and create a monitoring report, to review who's modifying the XML and when.
So, the problem is in moment, when I try to compare date of the XML file modified and today's date (`$filterDate`).

Initially I've got a folder full of XML files and I need to get from inside of these files date modified, user, and name of file. I added example of XML code.

Right now, the part with `Where-Object {$_.TimeModified.Date -GE $filterDate}` didn't work with `-GE`, but if i try to put it `-LE`, it show me output from all files.

Example XML

```
<ModullarRule schema="3.2" id="2132135e" entrypoint="12321321321313ce2" design="118;51">
    <Name>AnyShit2Queue</Name>
    <Description/>
    <Comments/>
    <RuleAudit stamp="2132131237" version="0.SS@TEST.3">
        <SrvModified date="2018.11.29 09:35:11" user="User1"/>
        <XmlModified date="2017.12.05 17:13:49" user="User2"/>
        <SrvCreated date="2017.12.05 10:07:36" user="User2"/>
        <XmlCreated date="2017.12.05 10:07:36" user="User2"/>
    </RuleAudit>
</ModullarRule>
```

I'm trying to take the `<SrvModified>` part from the XML.

```
$Path = "C:\Test"
$filterDate = Get-Date -format "yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    [xml]$xml = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Where-Object {
        $_.TimeModified.Date -LE $filterDate
    }
    foreach ($item in $xml.ModullarRule.RuleAudit.SrvModified) {
        $Xml.ModullarRule.RuleAudit.SrvModified | Select date, user 
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: A time in the past is less than a time in the future. Since `$filterdate` is the time when the code runs, then any date in the past will be less than that.

Comment: When i use $filterDate like  $filterDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Date, i got same error. I need to convert it to format of TimeModified at first?

Comment: When doing comparisons of unlike types, the LHS (left-hand side) dictates the object types being compared. Since you did not cast either side, the `$_.TimeModified.Date` is considered a string and makes `$filterdate` a string as well. You need to cast it like `[datetime]$_.TimeModified.Date`.

Comment: What is `.TimeModified.Date` supposed to be anyway? None of the objects you are dealing with even has this property, as far as I can see.

Comment: I hope .TimeModified.Date it is last time what this file was modified, what you can see in file properties in Windows. Found it somethere in internet btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I have interpreted your question, you want to select `@date` and `@user` attributes of all `<SrvModified>` where the `@date` is greater than a given reference date, for example "two days ago", in all XML files in the target folder.

One could do it using `Where-Object`:

```
$path = "C:\Test"
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).ToString('yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss')

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter '*.xml' -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $xmlPath = $_.FullName

    $xml = New-Object xml
    $xml.Load($xmlPath)

    $xml.ModullarRule.RuleAudit.SrvModified |
        Where-Object date -gt $refDate |
        Select-Object date, user, @{name="file"; expr={$xmlPath}}
}
```

Comment: So problem was that I initially decided not to compare with the value inside the xml, but took "modified date" from windows

Comment: Not really, because the modified date in Windows is called `.LastWriteTime`, not `.TimeModified`. Chances are that you compared against `null` because you accessed a property that does not exist.